# How should I use "ask" in "reported speech"?

Tags: word-usage, reported-speech

Question:

> Mother said to me, "You had better to take an umbrella with you.

Possible answers:

> 1.Mother asked me, that I had better to take an umbrella with me.
>
> 2.Mother asked me to take an umbrella with me.
>
> 3.Mother asked me that I should take an umbrella with me.
>
> 4.Mother asked that you take an umbrella with you.

If I change this sentence into reported speech, which of the sentence is suitable?

Comment: I'd say "My mother asked me to take an umbrella", but the second one is the only grammatically correct statement you gave.

Answer (score 3):

When your mother says "you had better", it's not a request- it's a fairly forceful polite suggestion- almost an order, so [ask](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ask) (which is a request) isn't really appropriate.

In sentences 1 and 3, you have either retained "had better" or replaced it with "should", so you can use the verb **say**

> 1) Mother said that I had better take an umbrella with me.
>   3) Mother said that I should take an umbrella with me.

Note that in 1) **had better** required an infinitive without **to**.

For sentence 2, [tell](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell) would work nicely to convey the idea that it's an practically order:

> 2) Mother told me to take an umbrella with me.

Sentence 4, when you report speech that's addressed to you, the personal pronoun changes from second person **you** to first person **I**.

> 4) Mother asked that I take an umbrella with me.

This is grammatically correct, as **ask** can take a that-clause, but it's very formal (something that a lawyer might say) and it is still a request, not firm advice.

You can the verb to suggest, or better [recommend](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/recommend): both require a that-clause, and the latter conveys the idea of strong advice rather than a request:

> 4) Mother recommended that I take an umbrella with me.

Answer (score 1):

> My mother asked me to take an umbrella with me.

This is the *only* grammatically correct statement you gave.

> Mother asked me, that I had better to take an umbrella with me.

When you say "My mother asked me", you require a to infinitive, which you didn't supply here.

> Mother asked me that I should take an umbrella with me

This breaks the same rules as the first one, missing a to infinitive.

> Mother asked that you take an umbrella with you

Because you are talking to someone, the "you" in this context would be taken as meaning them, so really this says: "My mother asked that you take an umbrella", implying that your mother wants the person you are talking to to have an umbrella, not you.

Personally, I would say:

> My mother asked me to take an umbrella

As this eliminates confusion of who you are talking to, makes a clear statement that your mother asked you to take an umbrella, and is shorter than your original statement.

Comment: Dear downvoter, remember it's really useful if you leave a comment explaining why you downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The sentences 2 and 3 are grammatical.

The sentence #1 is ungrmmatical. You use an infinitive without to after the phrase "had better".

As for the sentence #4, mother is talking to you, not the person you are talking to. So you should use the sentence #2 instead.

But you had better use the following sentences in reported speech:

Mother said I had better take an umbrella with me.

Mother advised me to take an umbrella with me.

Answer (score 1):

> "You had better take an umbrella with you."

[no *to* sign before the infinitive]

*"You'd better do something"* is used to give advice which, if you follow it, may prevent some possible negative consequences.

And with the advice put in reported speech, the construction *tell + object + to-infinitive* is used [(one of the numerous sources)](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/cw-say-tell.htm).

So, the grammatically correct sentence would be

> Mother told me to take an umbrella with me.

If the head sentence was

> Mother said to me: "Please, take an umbrella with you",

the choice would be

> Mother asked me to take an umbrella with me.

Cut to the chase, in reported speech use *ask* for requests, and *tell* for advice (and orders), the alternatives for the latter being the verbs *advise, recommend* etc.